# Remote Desktop Connection monitors

Tags: rdp

I log into my work pc from home via VPN + Remote Desktop Connection.

When I log into my work PC, do the monitors invoke at work or stay locked and inactive?

In other words, when I working from home on my work pc, do others standing near my pc can see what I'm doing?

Comment: For example: with TeamViewer i control remote pc 100%, like i'm working on it, so i have to turn off monitors before leaving work.

Answer (score 1):

No, RDP takes over the console of the computer.

They however will be able to see on your monitor that You are `logged in remotely` to that specific computer.

They will see this for example:
http://msblog.blob.core.windows.net/wordpress/2010/11/17a043334c6bd9a1d37194f78df0af21.png

Comment: Yes, but for example, monitors at work will show login screen or unlocked pc?

Comment: It will show that the computer is in use by you, but they can't see whats happening